# TSQL: Parse By Word, Not Specific Character

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, xml-parsing, sql-server-2008-r2

I've looked for `TSQL` code to parse out by word, not character, as I have strings of `XML` in a table that need to be removed.  Unfortunately, they don't follow a precise formula, meaning there can be 5 to 20 `XML` strings, ie (in this case it's only 3):

```
<code>
<codeblue>Answer A</codeblue>
<codered>Blue Twenty</codered>
<codeyellow>WARNING: only push if active</codeyellow>
</code>
```

Between each are sometimes text or numbers, and I want each of these to be stored in columns:

```
CodeBlue                       |   CodeRed                         | CodeYellow
<codeblue>Answer A</codeblue>  |   <codered>Blue Twenty</codered>  | <codeyellow>WARNING: only push if active</codeyellow>
```

Of course, some columns will be `NULL`, as there may be anywhere from 5 to 20 `XML` strings.  Because of this, CHARINDEX won't properly extract, as I need to store the XML in column and thus `'<'` or `'>'` is not a correct identifier because the length can change depending on the text or numbers between the code.

My question is can I parse text by word or phrase, for instance, parse out `<codeblue>Answer B</codeblue>` out of a column of 8000 characters by searching for the keyword `codeblue`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to learn more about XML query methods.  This is relatively easy with a combination of the 'query' method which hunts down an element structure.  Then a 'value' which can then return an attribute or text value in the element.

```
declare @xml xml = '<code>
<codeblue>Answer A</codeblue>
<codered>Blue Twenty</codered>
<codeyellow>WARNING: only push if active</codeyellow>
</code>'

select 
    @Xml.query('//code/codeblue').value('.', 'varchar(max)') as codeBlue
,   @Xml.query('//code/codered').value('.', 'varchar(max)') as codeRed
,   @Xml.query('//code/codeyellow').value('.', 'varchar(max)') as codeYellow
```

References for XML methods: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190798.aspx

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server has built-in XQuery functionality which allows you to query XML in exactly the way you are asking.  Here is an example:

```
create table #t (x xml);

insert #t
select
'<code>
<codeblue>Answer A</codeblue>
<codebrown>ignore this</codebrown>
<codered>Blue Twenty</codered>
<codegreen>ignore this too</codegreen>
<codeyellow>WARNING: only push if active</codeyellow>
</code>';

select  Codes.n.value('codeblue[1]','varchar(max)') As CodeBlue
        , Codes.n.value('codered[1]','varchar(max)') As CodeRed
        , Codes.n.value('codeyellow[1]','varchar(max)') As CodeYellow
from    #t t
        cross apply t.x.nodes('/code') as Codes(n);
```